# What's wrong with "5"? Everything is just fine on the paper

Tags: c++, math

Here is the problem we should solve with C++:

```
GCD ( 2m , 2n )         =  2 * GCD( m , n )
GCD ( 2m , 2n+1 )       = GCD ( m , 2n+1 )
GCD ( 2m+1,  2n+1 ) = GCD ( n-m , 2m+1 )  (m<n)
GCD ( m , m )       = m
```

and here is the function i wrote:

```
int GCD(int n1, int n2)
{
    bool n1Zoj, n2Zoj;
    n1Zoj = (n1%2 == 0);
    n2Zoj = (n2%2 == 0);

    if(n1Zoj && n2Zoj)
        return 2 * GCD(n1/2, n2/2);

    if(n1Zoj && !n2Zoj)
        return GCD(n1/2, n2);

    if(!n1Zoj && !n2Zoj)
        return GCD((n2-n1)/2, n1);

    if(n1 == n2)
        return n1;
}
```

(*"Zoj" means "Even" in my language(persian) )

when i pass 5 as the second argument, program crashes and prints this message:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Exit code is `139`. I'm using Code::Blocks on ubuntu 12.04 that uses g++ as compiler.

UPDATE: Program crashes with 5,10,15,20,25,...

UPDATE: i think the correct form of function is:

```
int GCD(int n1, int n2)
{
    if (n1 > n2)
        std::swap(n1, n2);

    //std::cout<<"GCD is called with params: "<<n1<<" & "<<n2<<std::endl;
    bool n1Zoj, n2Zoj;

    n1Zoj = (n1%2 == 0);
    n2Zoj = (n2%2 == 0);

    if(n1 == n2)
        return n1;

    if(n1Zoj && n2Zoj)
        return 2 * GCD(n1/2, n2/2);

    if(n1Zoj && !n2Zoj)
        return GCD(n1/2, n2);

    if(!n1Zoj && n2Zoj)
        return GCD(n2/2, n1);

    if(!n1Zoj && !n2Zoj)
        return GCD((n2-n1)/2, n1);
}
```

Comment: What happens if all the tests fail, i.e., GCD(odd, even)?

Comment: I believe your line `return 2 * GCD (n1, n2)` should be `return 2 * GCD(n1/2, n2/2)` since it is a mapping for this line `GCD ( 2m , 2n )         =  2 * GCD( m , n )`

Comment: yeah, u r right, my mistake, but when i fixed this it became worse!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When `(n1Zoj && n2Zoj)` evaluates to true, what do you do? You call

```
return 2 * GCD(n1, n2);
```

which calls the function with the **exact same parameters**, resulting in infinite recursion, a blown out stack, and a stack overflow (segmentation fault).

Protip - learn to debug - I can't emphasize how **extremely important** this is.

Comment: That program can infinitely recur in more than one way. For example GCD(0, [odd number])

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yes I got it, all of them

Comment: @AndreiTita yes, true, that's just the one that jumped out :)

Comment: Not to mention what happens with `GCD(5, 2)`.  There's something missing in the original specification.

Comment: no, i copy-pasted the problem, btw, it mentions that m<n. 
I did not made this up! It's my homework ! http://mohammad.ehdaie.com/cv.htm
http://mohammad.ehdaie.com/HW4.doc <- you may need google translate if u r interested